# Tests and python package structure

Tags: python, package

I have some problems in structuring my python project. Currently it is a bunch of files in the same folder. I have tried to structure it like

```
proj/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  ...
  bar/
    __init__.py
    foobar.py
    ...
  tests/
    foo_test.py
    foobar_test.py
    ...
```

The problem is that I'm not able, from inner directories, to import modules from the outer directories. This is particularly annoying with tests.

I have read [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) about relative imports and [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) about relative imports from the main module. But both these methods require the base package to be in my PYTHONPATH. Indeed I obtain the following error

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.

So I added the following boilerplate code on top of the test files

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.pardir))
```

Still I get the same error. What is the correct way to

- structure a package, complete with tests, and
- add the base directory to the path to allow imports?

**EDIT** As requested in the comment, I add an example import that fails (in the file `foo_test.py`)

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.pardir))
from ..foo import Foo
```

Comment: Can you show an example import that fails?

Comment: Also, please include the value for your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` is just empty right now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use the `-m` switch to run code, the current directory is added to `sys.path`. So the easiest way to run your tests is from the parent directory of `proj`, using the command:

```
python -m proj.tests.foo_test
```

To make that work, you will need to include an `__init__.py` file in your tests directory so that the tests are correctly recognised as part of the package.

Comment: Thank you! So what I was missing was that `tests` itself should be a package. It was a rather stupid mistake, but I could not figure out it.

Answer (score 5):

I like to import modules using the full `proj.NAME` package prefix whenever possible. This is the approach the [Google Python styleguide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Packages#Packages) recommends.

One option to allow you to keep your package structure, use full package paths, and still move forward with development would be to use a virtualenv and put your project in develop mode. Your project's `setup.py` will need to use `setuptools` instead of `distutils`, to get the `develop` command.

This will let you avoid the `sys.path.append` stuff above:

```
% virtualenv ~/virt
% . ~/virt/bin/activate
(virt)~% cd ~/myproject
(virt)~/myproject% python setup.py develop
(virt)~/myproject% python tests/foo_test.py
```

Where `foo_test.py` uses:

```
from proj.foo import Foo
```

Now when you run `python` from within your virtualenv your `PYTHONPATH` will point to all of the packages in your project. You can create a shorter shell alias to enter your virtualenv without having to type `. ~/virt/bin/activate` every time.

Comment: It seems interesting. I will have to investigate this virtualenv tool. Does it allow me to work in a virtual environment where I can have access to the current dir as a package? Or is it simply a tool with an isolated python distribution - more like a chroot - where I have to install my package each time before using it?

Comment: It is a quick way of creating an isolated Python environment that you can blow away and recreate quickly.  Good for trying out modules using pip/easy_install without polluting your system Python. The virtualenv `activate` script inserts the `~/virt/bin` dir to the front of your `PATH` so that `~/virt/bin/python` is found before the system python.  The `develop` command links your project's packages into the `~/virt/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages` using a `.pth` file. It also modifies the `PS1` prompt to let you know you're "inside" the virtualenv.

Comment: Good advice, although these days you may want to choose `distribute` as a more actively maintained alternative to `setuptools`.

Comment: Agree, `setuptools` is in wider use but folks should be moving over to `distribute`, which is compatible and actively maintained.